# Save first column to file whose name is given by second column

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have a file which has 315 lines and 2 columns. The first column is individuals and second column is population ID, looks like this:

```
HT170_SD2W-14   HA_16
Q093_MK7-13 HA_25
Q87_MK3-2   HA_21
HT225_KS2A-23R  HA_7
HT256_KS2A-4    HA_7
HT216_SD2A-32   HA_15
ED19_SD1A40-3_357   HA_13
```

I want to extract individuals that belong to each population and save them for each population in a separate file to
get something like this for HA_7:

```
HT225_KS2A-23R
HT256_KS2A-4
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ f = "pop-" $2 ".txt" ; print $1 >f }' file
```

For the given input, this will generate the following files:

```
$ ls -l pop-*.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  18 Sep 28 18:47 pop-HA_13.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  14 Sep 28 18:47 pop-HA_15.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  14 Sep 28 18:47 pop-HA_16.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  10 Sep 28 18:47 pop-HA_21.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  12 Sep 28 18:47 pop-HA_25.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  28 Sep 28 18:47 pop-HA_7.txt

$ cat pop-HA_7.txt
HT225_KS2A-23R
HT256_KS2A-4
```

The `awk` program creates the output filename by taking the second field and prepending and appending suitable filename bits to it. Then it outputs the first field to that file.

Comment: Why the temporary variable?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas To avoid `sprintf()`. You can't output to `"pop-" $2 ".txt"`, it's a syntax error. Just easier in this instance.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right it looks like it fails in awk implementations based on the original nawk (not awk). Sounds like a bug (including POSIX conformance one). For them, you need `awk '{print $1 > ("old-" $2 ".txt")}'`. gawk, mawk, the 70s awk, busybox awk are OK.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for looking at it. I may post a bug report to the OpenBSD people about it.

Comment: Double-check the POSIX spec first. I only skimmed it. Given that the behaviour is shown on the implementation the POSIX spec is based on, it may have text to allow it even if the grammar doesn't. Note that the grammar  there implies that `print 1 > 2 > 3` should be treated as `print 1 > (2 > 3)` which is the case in mawk and busybox awk, but  not gawk. So gawk would have a bug as well.

Comment: [I've raised the question on the austin group ML](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg01602.html)